# Set system proxy settings from a python script on Ubuntu 13.04 (raring)

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, proxy, settings

I am writing a python script to change the system-wide proxy settings for various tasks depending on user settings.

Various (shell) solutions posted on the internet use `gsettings` or `gconftool-2`, so I gave that a try

I have tried using `gsettings`

```
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host '%s'" % host)
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port %d" % port)
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'")
```

(or, to disable the proxy)

```
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'")
```

as well as `gconftool-2`

```
os.system("gconftool-2 --type string --set /system/proxy/mode manual")
os.system("gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /system/http_proxy/use_http_proxy true")
os.system("gconftool-2 --type string --set /system/http_proxy/host %s" % host)
os.system("gconftool-2 --type integer --set /system/http_proxy/port %d" % port)
os.system("gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /system/http_proxy/use_same_proxy true")
```

(to disable:)

```
os.system("gconftool-2 --type string --set /system/proxy/mode none")
```

However, both of these did not seem to change anything. Neither did the settings in the "Network proxy" tab of the Network settings change, nor did my computer start/stop connecting to the proxy server. I suspect it might be because `gsettings` and `gconftool-2` are both GNOME tools and Ubuntu uses Unity, but I am not sure about this and the Internet does not know of any Unity alternative...

*Edit:*

I've been running both tools and this program as root, nothing changes...

Comment: Linux doesn't have a true concept of a system-wide proxy; different tools use different means of picking up a proxy. What tool/app are you testing this with?

Comment: After `os.system` runs those commands on the shell, I check if the proxy has changed both using the normal GUI system settings and using `wireshark` on a normal internet connection with `chromium` (it does use the system settings), which both tell me that the settings have not changed (I am still [not] connecting to the proxy)

Comment: look for dbus interfaces of those tools rather than trying these weird command lines.

Comment: @androyd Do these commands work if you run them from a normal shell as the same user?

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt - yes they do

Comment: Probably has to do something with authentication. Try running the script with sudo. (specifically with sudo so that the user's home is set right.)

Comment: Sorry that I did not write it in the question - it is in fact run as root already (tried both sudo and su)